# Invalid class string classic asp error

Tags: asp-classic

I have classic asp project which is running fine is production server but if i download all files from production server and copy it to my local machine and when i try to run through Internet Information services . I am getting error

```
"Invalid class string 
/MSD/includes/incCommon.asp, line 425"
```

and if i go to line 425

```
Set oData = Server.CreateObject("Data.CDatabase")
```

this is 425 line number..anyone knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to Register the dll which provides the CDatabase class with regsvr32 i think

Comment: well i do not know where the dlls of your Project exist. try to search for something like '\*data\*.dll' or so

Comment: i have searched entire project for .dll and found no match :(

Comment: have you searched on your production folder?

Comment: i meant Server not folder

Comment: @Spenzo search for the DLL using [this utility](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html), hopefully it will be easy to find. Then when you have its location, copy to your local machine and use `regsvr32 [path of dll]` to register.

Comment: I have got the CDatabase.cls file now how do i register with regsvr32 ?